# FreeBSD 8.2 : Can't login x window session (gnome)

Tags: gnome, freebsd

Environment:

OS: FreeBSD 8.2 64 bit

GNOME: I don't know how to check gnome's version in console. I install it from the latest port collection via internet.

Issue:

Each time I boot the OS, it display the login window. And I input my username and credential, then it begin to login, and I can see the desktop has been displayed, and I also see some icons in the desktop. Suddenly, the user is logged out automatically and back to the login window.

I've tried both common user and root, neither works.

I've mount the proc file system.

I've enable gnome in rc.conf

I've add '/usr/local/bin/gnome-session' to the ~/.xinitrc

I'll be very grateful if you can give me any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.xinitrc`, make sure that the last command (probably `gnome-session`) does *not* end with an ampersand (&). If that's the case, the `.xinitrc` will finish, and GDM will respawn the login screen. At least it used to be this way.

Otherwise, try with KDE or other WMs (like twm) instead, and see if they behave differently.
That could give you a clue.